# Find most common hash value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:
`h = Hash["a","foo", "b","bar", "c","foo"]`
I would like to return the most common value, in this case `foo`. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562256/find-most-common-string-in-an-array), but adapted to hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this:

```
h = Hash["a","foo", "b","bar", "c","foo", "d", "bar", 'e', 'foobar']
p h.values.group_by { |e| e }.max_by{|_,v| v.size}.first
# >> "foo"
```

**UPDATE(slower than my first solution)**

```
h = Hash["a","foo", "b","bar", "c","foo"]
h.group_by { |_,v| v }.max_by{|_,v| v.size}.first
# >> "foo"
```

**Benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

def seanny123(h)
  h.values.group_by { |e| e }.values.max_by(&:size).first
end

def stefan(h)
  frequencies = h.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k,v), h| h[v] += 1 }
  value, count = frequencies.max_by { |k, v| v }
  value
end

def yevgeniy_anfilofyev(h)
  h.group_by{|(_,v)| v }.sort_by{|(_,v)| v.size }[-1][0]
end

def acts_as_geek(h)
  v = h.values
  max = v.map {|i| v.count(i)}.max
  v.select {|i| v.count(i) == max}.uniq
end

def squiguy(h)
  v = h.values
  v.reduce do |memo, val|
    v.count(memo) > v.count(val) ? memo : val
  end
end

def babai1(h)
  h.values.group_by { |e| e }.max_by{|_,v| v.size}.first
end

def babai2(h)
  h.group_by { |_,v| v }.max_by{|_,v| v.size}.first
end


def benchmark(h,n)
  Benchmark.bm(20) do |x|
    x.report("Seanny123")           { n.times { seanny123(h) } }
    x.report("Stefan")              { n.times { stefan(h) } }
    x.report("Yevgeniy Anfilofyev") { n.times { yevgeniy_anfilofyev(h) } }
    x.report("acts_as_geek")        { n.times { acts_as_geek(h) } }
    x.report("squiguy")             { n.times { squiguy(h) } }
    x.report("Babai1")               { n.times { babai1(h) } }
    x.report("Babai2")               { n.times { babai2(h) } }
  end
end

n = 10
h = {}
1000.times do |i|
  h["a#{i}"] = "foo"
  h["b#{i}"] = "bar"
  h["c#{i}"] = "foo"
end
benchmark(h, n)
```

**Result:-**

```
                           user     system      total        real
Seanny123              0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.015550)
Stefan                 0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.044666)
Yevgeniy Anfilofyev    0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.023162)
acts_as_geek          16.160000   0.000000  16.160000 ( 16.223582)
squiguy               15.740000   0.000000  15.740000 ( 15.768917)
Babai1                 0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.015430)
Babai2                 0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.025711)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the values as an array and then just plug into the solution you linked.

```
h.values.group_by { |e| e }.values.max_by(&:size).first
#=> foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the frequencies with [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
frequencies = h.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, (k,v)| h[v] += 1 ; h }
#=> {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>1}
```

Or [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
frequencies = h.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k,v), h| h[v] += 1 }
#=> {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>1}
```

And the maximum with [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
value, count = frequencies.max_by { |k, v| v }
#=> ["foo", 2]

value
#=> "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Benchmarks

**With a small hash:**

```
n = 100000
h = Hash["a","foo", "b","bar", "c","foo"]
benchmark(h, n)
```

Results:

```
                           user     system      total        real
Seanny123              0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.222342)
Stefan                 0.260000   0.000000   0.260000 (  0.263583)
Yevgeniy Anfilofyev    0.350000   0.000000   0.350000 (  0.341685)
acts_as_geek           0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.306601)
squiguy                0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.139141)
Babai                  0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.218616)
```

**With a large hash:**

```
n = 10
h = {}
1000.times do |i|
  h["a#{i}"] = "foo"
  h["b#{i}"] = "bar"
  h["c#{i}"] = "foo"
end
benchmark(h, n)
```

Results:

```
                           user     system      total        real
Seanny123              0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.059068)
Stefan                 0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.100760)
Yevgeniy Anfilofyev    0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.080988)
acts_as_geek          97.020000   0.020000  97.040000 ( 97.072220)
squiguy               97.480000   0.020000  97.500000 ( 97.535130)
Babai                  0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.058653)
```

**Benchmark code:**

```
require 'benchmark'

def seanny123(h)
  h.values.group_by { |e| e }.values.max_by(&:size).first
end

def stefan(h)
  frequencies = h.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k,v), h| h[v] += 1 }
  value, count = frequencies.max_by { |k, v| v }
  value
end

def yevgeniy_anfilofyev(h)
  h.group_by{|(_,v)| v }.sort_by{|(_,v)| v.size }[-1][0]
end

def acts_as_geek(h)
  v = h.values
  max = v.map {|i| v.count(i)}.max
  v.select {|i| v.count(i) == max}.uniq
end

def squiguy(h)
  v = h.values
  v.reduce do |memo, val|
    v.count(memo) > v.count(val) ? memo : val
  end
end

def babai(h)
  h.values.group_by { |e| e }.max_by{|_,v| v.size}.first
end


def benchmark(h,n)
  Benchmark.bm(20) do |x|
    x.report("Seanny123")           { n.times { seanny123(h) } }
    x.report("Stefan")              { n.times { stefan(h) } }
    x.report("Yevgeniy Anfilofyev") { n.times { yevgeniy_anfilofyev(h) } }
    x.report("acts_as_geek")        { n.times { acts_as_geek(h) } }
    x.report("squiguy")             { n.times { squiguy(h) } }
    x.report("Babai")               { n.times { babai(h) } }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Don't use my solution.  My computer had to use a lot of clock cycles to compute it.  Didn't know a functional approach would be so slow here.

How about using [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)?

```
h = Hash["a","foo", "b","bar", "c","foo"]
v = h.values
most = v.reduce do |memo, val|
         v.count(memo) > v.count(val) ? memo : val
       end
p most
```

As a caveat, this will only return one value if two or more share the same "max" count value in the hash.  If you care about all the "max" values, this is not a solution to use.

Here is a benchmark.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'benchmark'

MULT = 10
arr = []
letters = ("a".."z").to_a
10000.times do
  arr << letters.sample
end
10000.times do |i|
  h[i] = arr[i]
end

Benchmark.bm do |rep|
  rep.report("Seanny123") {
    MULT.times do
      h.values.group_by { |e| e }.values.max_by(&:size).first
    end
  }

  rep.report("squiguy") {
    MULT.times do
      v = h.values
      most = v.reduce do |memo, val|
        v.count(memo) > v.count(val) ? memo : val
      end
    end
  }

  rep.report("acts_as_geek") {
    MULT.times do
      v = h.values
      max = v.map {|i| v.count(i)}.max
      v.select {|i| v.count(i) == max}.uniq
    end
  }

  rep.report("Yevgeniy Anfilofyev") {
    MULT.times do
      h.group_by{|(_,v)| v }
       .sort_by{|(_,v)| v.size }[-1][0]
    end
  }

  rep.report("Stefan") {
    MULT.times do
      frequencies = h.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, (k,v)| h[v] += 1 ; h }
      value, count = frequencies.max_by { |k, v| v }
    end
  }

  rep.report("Babai") {
    MULT.times do
      h.values.group_by { |e| e }.max_by{|_,v| v.size}.first
    end
  }

end
```

Comment: @Seanny123 I'll do that for you; if you give me a little time to make it meaningful.

Comment: @Seanny123 Added the benchmark.  I need help to make a better random hash.

Comment: *For some reason my random array to hash only makes it a size of 26* - that's because of `a..z`, hash keys are unique ;)

Comment: @Stefan I'm embarrassed! Shoot I better use digits instead then.

Answer (score 0):

With `group_by` but without `values` and with `sort_by`:

```
h.group_by{|(_,v)| v }
 .sort_by{|(_,v)| v.size }[-1][0]
```