# Method to find the name most used in an array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array of items. I need a method of finding which item repeats the most in the array

```
array = "Car","Car","Bank","Plane","Boat","Car","Car","Ship"
```

I need a method to look at this array and print the item that shows the most.

Output should be:

```
=> "Car"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562256/find-most-common-string-in-an-array

Comment: This question is asked of numbers in an array. My question is matching words in an array I cant use a method that finds the largest number

Comment: The user there was also using strings, they just happened to be strings that contained numbers

Comment: So the answers on that question is confusing to me because I need the method to not take the first item and look for duplicates but to look at each item for duplicates of that item and then choose whichever item has the most duplicates.

Comment: How would i tell my       select method to compare itself to the next item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 'possible duplicate' link suggests a pretty great answer. To use it on your array:

```rb
irb > %w(Car Car Bank Plane Boat Car Car Ship).group_by(&:itself).max_by(&:size).first
=> "Car"
```

This groups all the values together (cars with cars, planes with planes), picks the biggest group, and returns one member of that group.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562256/find-most-common-string-in-an-array)

Comment: This sems good but I wont know the items in the array so I cant put the items names like your answer suggest. I would only know that the array has items

Comment: Oh, ok. That is what variables are for. Calling these methods on a variable called `array` will accomplish the same thing, even if (for whatever reason) you don't know what is inside `array`.

    `mystery_array.group_by(&:itself).max_by(&:size).first`

Comment: Ok one more thing what about if I have an array of hashes and I want to get the array items from one of the hashes in each item of the array?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Some code would be helpful, probably as a separate question.